# jquery Ajax logo delete not working after first ajax success Laravel 7 jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-7

I am coding a logo ajax crud in laravel, it is working on uploads very well, but after deleting one logo the remove button stops working I have tried through many ways but all in vein, maybe I am making a mistake that is not visible to me yet, please guide me thanks

here's my blade code:

```
<div class="logos_append">
@if(count($logos)>0)
        @foreach($logos as $logo)
        <div class="m-3">
        <img class="companylogoimg img-fluid" width="100" height="50" src="{{asset('carchain_private/public/src/uploads/Logos/'.'u_'. $logo->user_id.'/'.$logo->name)}}" >
        <span data-id="{{$logo->id}}" data-name="{{$logo->name}}" data-user_id="{{$logo->user_id}}" class="btn btn-primary delete_logo">x</span>
  remove

        <!--<input type="hidden" id="logo_id" value="{{$logo->id}}">-->
        
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <input type="hidden" id="logo_count"value="{{count($logos)}}">
        @else
        {{ __('You do not have any logos')}}
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

    <!--Modal for logos -->
    
    <div id="myModal" class="modal " role="dialog">

            <div class="">

                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

                        </button>

                        <h4 class="modal-title" align="center"><b>Crop image</b></h4>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div id="upload-logo"></div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <div id="RotateAntiClockwise" class="btn btn-primary" title="Rotate anti-clockwise"><span class="fa fa-rotate-left"></span></div>

                            <div id="RotateClockwise" class="btn btn-primary" title="Rotate clockwise"><span class="fa fa-rotate-right"></span></div>



                            <button class="popup-btn trader-btn  btn-primary company-logo-result">{{ __('Crop & Upload')}}</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

<!--End Modal for logos-->

    <!--Delete Logo modal-->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete this logo :</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" id="logo_id" value="">
          <div id="modal_img"></div>
        {{ __('This logo will be deleted.')}} 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{{ __('Close')}}</button>
        <button type="button" id="delete_complete" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Delete Logo')}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Delete Logo modal-->
```

Here's my jquery code:

```
<script>
    
    $('.delete_logo').on('click', function(){
        console.log(1);
        var logo_id = $(this).data('id');
        var logo_user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
        var logo_name = $(this).data('name');
        var base_url = "{{asset('/')}}";
        var general_path = "carchain_private/public/src/uploads/Logos/u_"+logo_user_id+"/"+logo_name;
        console.log(logo_id,logo_user_id,logo_name,base_url,general_path);
        $('#logo_id').val(logo_id);
        $('#modal_img').html('<img src="'+base_url+general_path+'">');
        $('#exampleModal').show();
        

    });
    
    $('#delete_complete').on('click', function(){
       var logo_id = $('#logo_id').val();
       console.log(logo_id);
       $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('delete_logo') }}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {logo_id:logo_id, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
                datatype:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#logos_append').html(data);
                    $('#exampleModal').hide();
                }
            });
    });
    
</script>
```

Here's my controller's code:

```
public function delete_logo(Request $request){
        
        $logo_id = $request->logo_id;
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $path = public_path(). '/src/uploads/Logos/'.'u_'. $user_id.'/';
        $logo = Logo::where('id','=',$logo_id)->get();
        if ($logo){
            foreach ($logo as $del){
                if (\File::exists($path . $del->name)) {

                    \File::delete($path . $del->name);



                }
                $del->delete();
            }
        }
        
        $logos = Logo::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get();
        return view('logos.logos_append',compact('logos'));
        
    }
```

[image]

it shows nothing in console as well no error from server side as well..

Comment: Hi ,here `$('#logos_append').html(data);` you are creating entire logos div again ? If yes then you need bind your selector with some static element . i.e : `$(document).on("click",".delete_logo",function(){` because elements are dynamically created .

Comment: I know you answer many questions related to javascript, thanks for your answer, i will try and  update you...

Comment: Working very well for me...

Comment: If you can write it as an answer, i will vote up to this... Thanks a lot..

Comment: done added as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `ajax` success function you are adding html to your `logos` divs  so when you will click next time on `delete_logo` button it will work because datas are added dynamically so you need to bind your button with some static element which is present in your `DOM` . i.e :

```
$(document).on("click",".delete_logo",function(){ //your code })
```

Comment: It solved my problem and also helped me to learn some forgotten concept as well.. Thanks a lot..